# Count specific string in text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to count specific strings in a file and save the value in a variable?

For me it would be the String "/export" (without quotes).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's one method:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content "YourFile.txt"
$Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "/export" -AllMatches

$Matches.Matches.Count
```

Comment: one liner : `(Select-String -Path "YourFile.txt" -Pattern "/export" -AllMatches).Matches.Count`

Comment: Gives "Out of Memory" on very large files, might need to use a streaming technique if working with huge files.

Comment: @NealWalters Do you have any more information on a streaming technique? I need to count occurrences of a string in a 6GB file: I expect about 5 million occurrences.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee - I can't remember now if I solved it or not.

Comment: @NealWalters I'll take that as a no :-) But thanks - I used your idea to come up with a solution that solved my problem.

Comment: I found that this gives the exact number of matches. I have experimented in a file containing 1104191 'the' word. After incrementing it by one more in a single line. It gave me 1104192.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way to do it.

```
$count = (get-content file1.txt | select-string -pattern "/export").length
```

As mentioned in comments, this will return the count of lines containing the pattern, so **if any line has more than one instance of the pattern, the count won't be correct**.

Comment: This returns the number of lines containing the string, not the total number of matches.

Comment: Can confirm what @AllenZ. says

Comment: Agreed. I've added a note on it to the answer. Decided not to delete my answer, as it's often a useful approach.

Comment: Please at lease put in bold "the count won't be correct"

Answer (score 6):

If you're searching in a large file (several gigabytes) that could have have millions of matches, you might run into memory problems. You can do something like this (inspired by a [suggestion from NealWalters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29889664/61754)):

```
Select-String -Path YourFile.txt -Pattern '/export' -SimpleMatch | Measure-Object -Line
```

This is not perfect because

- it counts the number of **lines** that contain the match, **not** the total number of matches.
- it prints some headings along with the count, rather than putting just the count into a variable.

You can probably solve these if you need to. But at least you won't run out of memory.

Answer (score -2):

```
grep -co vs grep -c
```

Both are useful and thanks for the "o" version. New one to me.

Comment: grep is not a thing in PowerShell.

Comment: @Phil It actually is, and very easily to get. Just install the Scoop package manager with `irm get.scoop.sh | iex` (https://scoop.sh) then simply install grep `scoop install grep`. All Unix/GNU utils are perfectly available and functional on Powershell.

Comment: my experience with powershell is use when you have to use whatever comes with windows. if you can install arbitrary packages, you can use something else entirely. certainly how to do x in y is not satisfactorily answered by install z